# Difference between 整理つける and 受け入れる

Tags: translation, words

I would like to know the difference between 整理つける and 受け入れる

> お嬢ちゃんには黙ったまま行くのか‌
>
> いまさら合わせる顔がない‌
>
> せめて気持ちの**整理**だけはつけさせてやれよ‌
>
> Are you gonna leave without saying a word to the young lady?‌
>
> I can't face her now.‌
>
> At least help her come to terms with it.‌

Both seem to mean: **to accept** but could 受け入れる fit in the context ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last sentence means, 'At least give her a chance (by seeing her and explaining with your own words) to **sort out her own feelings** so that she can **accept it**'.
She is probably shocked at some fact and at a loss how to deal with it.

受け入れる is the result and 気持ちの整理をつける (= 気持ちを整理する) is the process prior to the acceptance. So they are not the same but the latter is implied.